# If statement skipping internal code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, lookup-tables

First off this code is under an NDA, and I cannot show much more.
I am trying to get a star to show up on a sheet either as black or yellow. when the code gets past the sheet selection it skips back to the main code. I have tried another if then and the current Case formats. The code skips no matter what is in the cell it is suppose to look at. I put numbers, true, and false. The entire program is based on look up tables, and I am just trying to add code for the stars. Any help will be great.

```
  Sub Star()

  Range(Cells(nxtRow, "B"), Cells(nxtRow + 1, "B")).Select
  With Selection
    .MergeCells = True
  End With

   '8.3x11 sheet
    If (p_size = 1) Then
      y = 171.25 + 43.5 * Mtimes
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, 23.25, y, 22, 
        _22).Select
     Select Case Cells(i, "s").Value

    'chooses yellow

        Case True
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 13
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    'chooses black

        Case False
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        Case Else: MsgBox ("star color indeterminate")
        End Select


'11x17 sheet
    ElseIf (p_size = 2) Then
     y = 160 + 33 * Mtimes
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, 48#, y, 22, 22).Select

    Select Case Cells(i, "s").Value

    'chooses yellow

        Case True
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 13
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    'chooses black

        Case False
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        Case Else: MsgBox ("star color indeterminate")
        End Select

    End If

End Sub
```

Final fixed code. With Wookiee's help I got it to color correctly. So, I made 'i' a variable that is collected, and that fixed the skipping. I added worksheet ('d") to actually color the stars correctly by looking at the right spot.

```
  Sub Star(i)

  Range(Cells(nxtRow, "B"), Cells(nxtRow + 1, "B")).Select
With Selection
    .MergeCells = True
  End With

'8.3x11 sheet
  If (p_size = 1) Then
    y = 171.25 + 43.5 * Mtimes
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, 23.25, y, 
22, 22).Select
    Select Case Sheets("d").Cells(i, "s").Value

    'chooses yellow

        Case True
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 13
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 
 255, 255)

    'chooses black

        Case False
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 0
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        Case Else: MsgBox ("star color not found")
        End Select


'11x17 sheet
ElseIf (p_size = 2) Then
    y = 160 + 33 * Mtimes
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, 48#, y, 
  22, 22).Select

    Select Case Sheets("d").Cells(i, "s").Value

    'chooses yellow

        Case True
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 13
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 
  255, 255)

    'chooses black

        Case False
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 0
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64
            Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        Case Else: MsgBox ("star color not found")
        End Select
     Else: MsgBox ("paper size not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is "i" defined in `Select Case Cells(i, "s").Value`

Comment: In the previous operation. It is the number in a list of items up to 20. That reads fine every time I run this, and the lookup has False filled in to 105. When I run it with a break at the Select case it never stops.

Comment: oops sorry, I ran it again, and i is empty. I am a new programmer. Thank you.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer so you can mark it.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I do not know how to make that the answer it works now.

Comment: Skips the If?  Put an Else right before the End If and Msgbox p_size for us.  Let me know if that msgbox pops up.  Also if you are working in multiple workbooks and worksheets, your calls to range and cells should be explicit "without question, unique" by using a workbook and worksheet reference preceding it, how does the sub know?  also, p_size it is not defined in the sub, is it global to the workbook or module?  You must remember to initialize it in a place where it will always have a value, workbook.open maybe - these are my initial suggestions.

Comment: also i, not passed into the sub, so you are playing with it outside the sub as a mod or wb variable, what expectation do you have for it to be valid, perhaps add that to your msgbox along with nxtRow

Comment: Wookiee, The worksheet 'D' is a unique worksheet. This is a single workbook, and the look ups are in two specific worksheets. Thank you for pointing out the worksheet reference.

Comment: If Bill's suggestion did not fix the problem, you should NOT mark it as the answer - you can leave the upvote, but should not leave the checkmark. Either you or @Wookies-Will-Code should post that suggestion as an Answer and it should be marked as the answer. You shouldn't post the answer in your question.

Comment: Bill's fixed the problem, and then Wookie's fixed a problem that showed up after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of your "i" variable in your two lines:

```
Select Case Cells(i, "s").Value
```

It's possible that it's not in the range you are expecting.

Comment: Final fixed code. With Wookiee's help I got it to color correctly.